# Чтение из файла на c++

Tags: c++, xcode, файловая-система

Возникла проблема с чтением текста из файла на c++. Как я понял, чтобы исполняемый файл нашел нужный документ, необходимо узнать абсолютный путь до исполняемого файла и сформировать абсолютный путь до нужного документа. Неужели нет менее костыльного способа сделать это? Такое решение используется повсеместно? Может быть, проще перенести текущую директорию в папку приложения, если это возможно, и использовать относительный путь?

Comment: Скорее всего ваша ide немного обманывает Вас и выставляет другой рабочий каталог. Попробуйте с консоли запустить, когда приложения и файл рядом.

Comment: @KoVadim  через Xcode всё работает, я указывал там рабочий каталог в нужное место. Сейчас я запускаю приложение без ide, нужный файл положил в одну папку с ним. Исполняемый файл должен искать документ в той же папке, где лежит сам (путь состоит только из названия), но ничего не находит

Comment: а рабочий каталог меняете?

Comment: @KoVadim нет, была такая идея, но в другой теме посоветовали использовать абсолютный путь. Возможно поменять рабочий каталог на c++? Реализация этого зависит от используемой ос?

Comment: Поменять можно,  это ос зависимо. Скорее всего что то делаете лишнее. Может терминал чудит

Comment: @KoVadim что из себя представляют пакеты приложения mac? Насколько я понял, пакет с ресурсами и исполняемым файлом создаётся при компиляции приложения Xcode. Может быть, консольное приложение на  mac в принципе не могут иметь дополнительных файлов? Как из консольного приложения сделать обычное?

Comment: я не пользуюсь маком и там все дико для меня, но в консоли все должно выглядеть как обычный freebsd. А значит, если просто в консоли запустить приложение, оно должно найти файл рядом

Comment: А воспользоваться `argv[0]`, чтобы понять, где именно находится исполнимый файл, и плясать от этого, в mac/xcode можно?

Comment: да и в других ос можно. правда оно бывает иногда "левое"

Answer (score -1):

Если файл находится в той же директории, что и консольное приложение, то путь можно получить так (без необходимости переходить сначала в каталог с приложением)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto appPath = std::string(argv[0]);
    auto lastSlashIndex = appPath.find_last_of("\\/");
    
    if (lastSlashIndex == std::string::npos) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    appPath.erase(appPath.begin() + lastSlashIndex, appPath.end());
    
    std::cout << appPath.c_str() << std::endl;
    
    auto filePath = appPath + "/test.txt";
    
    std::cout << filePath.c_str() << std::endl;
    
    // read file at filePath ...
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы используете библиотеку std, то намного лучше использовать std::filesystem::path для работы с путями.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk согласен, но это доступно только с C++17